# Failed UDP connection in Docker container

Tags: php, docker

I am working on a laravel php application which seemed to running fine until I stopped working for the day by running the `docker-compose down` command. When I got back to working again by starting the container `docker-compose up -d`, the container started throwing a `failed connecting to udp` error. Below is the error I am getting
[image]

In my logs I can see some message

> [2022-09-07 07:25:09] local.ERROR: Failed connecting to udp://: (0: Failed to parse address ":") {"exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): Failed connecting to udp://: (0: Failed to parse address ":") at /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/SocketHandler.php:313)

Because of the error php exits and I can do practically nothing with the app at this point. Does anyone know how I can deal with the issue and get php state back to running?

Below is my docker file

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    gateway:
        build:
            context: services/vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/7.4
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-7.4/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '8000:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - './gateway:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - db1
            - redis
            - mailhog

    services:
        build:
            context: servvices/vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '8002:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5175}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - './loans:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - gateway
            - db2

    # gateway db
    db1:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${GATEWAY_DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${GATEWAY_DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${GATEWAY_DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${GATEWAY_DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'spg_db:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${GATEWAY_DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s

    # service db
    db2:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '3308:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${SERVICE_DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${SERVICE_DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${SERVICE_DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${SERVICE_DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'spl_db:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${SERVICE_DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s

    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s

    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail

networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    db1:
        driver: local
    db2:
        driver: local
    redis:
        driver: local
```

Comment: `udp://:` looks strange to me. Can you share more details, like the code involved?

Comment: What Nico said, also 'Failed to parse address ":" ' looks like you're missing the address parameter maybe

Comment: @NicoHaase I have added the docker file to show more details

Comment: If this is a PHP problem, please share the PHP code, along with your attempts to resolve the problem.

Comment: @NicoHaase it doesn't look like a php problem. The container starts but php exits because of the failed connection. Looks like a network thing, I can't place what it is though

Comment: You've tagged this with PHP - why did you do that, if this is not a PHP problem? The error message looks like one thrown by PHP, and the address you try to use (`udp://:`) looks strange - where did you configure that? What have you tried to resolve this problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have no idea where `udp://:` is from as I have not configured it anywhere. I also tagged `php` since I wasn't sure why i was getting the error